# asp.net 5 vnext integration testing and views

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building a new app using ASP.NET 5 with MVC6 and trying to set up a project with tests based on [this](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/testing/integration-testing.html) description.

It is working fine for API calls (returning ObjectResults), but when I hit a response returning a view, I get 404 response.

I am using startup class from the project unter test, and the code is the same as in tutorial:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");


        }

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
}

[Route("/")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("/")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("/ok")]
    public IActionResult Ok()
    {
        return new ObjectResult("OK");
    }

}

[TestClass]
public class HomeTests
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public HomeTests()
    {
        var server = new TestServer(TestServer.CreateBuilder()
            .UseStartup<Startup>());
        _client = server.CreateClient();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Index_returns_page()
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("/");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //Assert.Equals("OK", responseString);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Index_OK_returns_OK()
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("/ok");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Assert.AreEqual("OK", responseString);
    }
}
```

Of course in the browser everything works as expected.

Comment: Can you share the code for `Startup` that you use in `UseStartup<>`

Comment: I've added full startup and test class code

Comment: Is the controller correct? Is it working in the browser? Did you try debugging your controller?

Comment: I've added controller code. Everything works fine in the browser. Also test for /ok passes correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't find your views because the IApplicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath is set to the test project's directory. You should be replacing the IApplicationEnvironment implementation with your own that points at the project you're testing. This will get a bit easier in RC2.

Comment: This is a simple project demonstrating a solution: https://github.com/mdymel/AspNetCoreRazorTests